# Make EF Core 2 work with a getter only property without a backing field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My goal is to make Entity Framework 2 play nice with the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; } // This should NOT change

    public string NotRequiredProperty {get; set;}

    public Foo(Guid id) => Id = id;

    private Foo() { } // Empty constructor is necessary for EF Core I believe?
}
```

I have read [this blog post](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/11/07/efcorefields/) that says the following can be done:

```
// Class
private Guid _id;
public Guid Id => _id;

// Configuration
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
.Property(b => b.Id)
.UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.FieldDuringConstruction);
```

Which COULD work.

The only improvement I see here is that I am required to explicitly declare a private backing field even though a `{ get; }` means that one is created implicitly.

How can I make EF Core work with JUST a `{ get; }` (and of course some required entity configuration)

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking is possible *in general* with EF Core 2.1 introduced [Entity types with constructors with parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors) feature. You don't need the empty constructor anymore - EF Core will be able to use the constructor with `Guid id` parameter.

However there are two limitations which apply to your `Id` property. First, it's a **read-only** property (hence is backed by `readonly` field which can be set only from a constructor). The equivalent in your explicit backing field example would be if you define it as `private readonly Guid _id;`. Then the sample configuration WON'T work.

The documentation section for [Read-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#read-only-properties) says:

> Once properties are being set via the constructor it can make sense to make some of them read-only. EF Core supports this, but there are some things to look out for:
>
> - Properties without setters are not mapped by convention. (Doing so tends to map properties that should not be mapped, such as computed properties.)
> - Using automatically generated key values requires a key property that is read-write, since the key value needs to be set by the key generator when inserting new entities.

Pay attention to the second bullet, because that's the second problem. The `Id` property by convention is a PK, and `Guid` and numeric type PKs by convention are *auto-generated*.

So you need to choose between two options - either make the `Id` *non read-only* by adding `private set;` as suggested in the link, or (which is the answer of the question *"How can I make EF Core work with JUST a `{ get; }`"*) make it *non auto-generated*  by using the following fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .Property(e => e.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Technically, adding a `private set` does not answer my question since I want to ONLY use a ` { get; }`;  my constructor should only be able to change it.

So you say if I configure `Id` with `ValueGeneratedNever()` that my example would work exactly like the way I want it as long as I pass a `GUID` in the constructor?

Comment: @S.tenBrinke Indeed, that was the answer to the exact question. And yes, you should pass an existing `Guid` or `Guid.NewGuid()` for new entity to the entity constructor. This basically has nothing to do with EF - it's C# (CLR) requirement for read-only fields - they can only be set in class constructor.

Comment: What about private setter, note that your example with explicit `private Guid _id;` field without `readonly` modifier is equivalent of having private setter, because the backing field can be set from anywhere inside the class or via reflection. As I mentioned in the answer, if you mark the field as `readonly`, you would get the same issue as with the implicit `get` only property and will be forced to use the same solution `ValueGeneratedNever` and pass the `Id` value *only* via constructor.